# How can I connect the Object Storage with WML(Watson Machine Learning) service?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'd like to connect the object storage with WML(Watson Machine Learning Service) in IBM Cloud.

I uploaded a stream model file(.str) to WML and this model has multiple input file nodes(3 csv files and 13 sad files).

So, I put those input files into Object Storage and changed model's nodes to use Object Storage's file in Data Science Experience.
But that changed model(modified in DSX) couldn't be uploaded to WML.(ERROR: models refer to undefined field)